# DPDK packet drop?

Tags: c++, networking, packet-capture, dpdk

I am trying to debug a issue related to packet loss when using DPDK. When using the application without DPDK, there is no issue seen.

To explain:
I have a process A which receives packets from process B (from different server).

Initial issue:
When DPDK is enabled in process A, for first few seconds, the packet flow is fine, however after few minutes the process A stops receiving any packets.
**What can be possible reason for this ? I have confirmed packets are being sent by process B.**

*To debug this:*
I have enabled pdump feature in my application so that I can take packet capture using dpdk-pdump.
While debugging, I see that, the server is receiving packets when I check using dpdk-proc-info

```
[root@QVr740-6 app]# ./dpdk-proc-info   -- --stats -p 0x1
EAL: Cannot find resource for device
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created

  ######################## NIC statistics for port 0  ########################
  **RX-packets: 11595973**    RX-errors:  0           RX-bytes:  17231595358
  RX-nombuf:  0
  TX-packets: 0           TX-errors:  0           TX-bytes:  22

  ############################################################################
```

However, when I take try taking packet capture :

```
[root@QVr740-6 app]# ./dpdk-pdump -l 42,44,46  --   --pdump 'device_id=0000:18:00.1,queue=*,rx-dev=/home/cu1/nmurshed/capture.pcap'
EAL: Detected 56 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket_69588_2a3baabe32a56
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_i40e (8086:1572) device: 0000:18:00.1 (socket 0)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_i40e (8086:1572) device: 0000:18:00.2 (socket 0)
EAL: Cannot find resource for device
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Port 2 MAC: 02 70 63 61 70 01
 core (42), capture for (1) tuples
 - port 0 device (0000:18:00.1) queue 65535
^C

Signal 2 received, preparing to exit...
##### PDUMP DEBUG STATS #####
 -packets dequeued:                     0
 -packets transmitted to vdev:          0
 -packets freed:                        0
```

How to find out where these packets are dropping ?
I did confirm that dpdk-pdump works when issue is not seen.

Any hints will be valuable as I have been tearing my hair on this.

EDIT:

I missed something in the stats. I see that Rx-missed_errors keep increasing at an alarming rate when the issue occurs.

````
Wed Oct 20 18:47:46 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 0
Wed Oct 20 18:47:47 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 0
Wed Oct 20 18:47:48 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 0
Wed Oct 20 18:47:49 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 8216
Wed Oct 20 18:47:50 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 32384
Wed Oct 20 18:47:51 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 56510
Wed Oct 20 18:47:52 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 80636
Wed Oct 20 18:47:53 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 104762
Wed Oct 20 18:47:54 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 128882
Wed Oct 20 18:47:55 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 152960
Wed Oct 20 18:47:56 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 177086
Wed Oct 20 18:47:57 PDT 2021```

I increased the rx/tx desc in  rte_eth_rx_queue_setup which delays the problem. Somehow, my application is not freeing the rx_desc.

Question.. is each packet received == 1 rx_desc?
Is it possible that my application takes too long time to process packet ? or is it like I am not freeing them ?
````

Comment: what do you mean by without dpdk the packet flow is fine, who is receiving packets without dpdk?

Comment: What I mean is.. I have a way to build process A without DPDK.. so dpdk is not in the picture then.

Comment: @numrshed please add the compile flags (static or shared) mode for DPDK, a snippet of DPDK API calls in process A and the arguments used for rte_eal_init. From the current question explained `you are referring to packet drop as process B (pdump) not receiving packets`. is this the right understanding?

Comment: Hi @vipin, I missed the rx_missed_errors counter... Initially the counter is 0..then it starts increasing.. which explains the drop                                                                

Wed Oct 20 18:47:48 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 0
Wed Oct 20 18:47:49 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 8216
Wed Oct 20 18:47:50 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 32384
Wed Oct 20 18:47:51 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 56510
Wed Oct 20 18:47:52 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 80636
Wed Oct 20 18:47:53 PDT 2021
rx_missed_errors: 104762

Comment: Yes, correct.. my application itself doesn't receive packets ..which I now believe is due to rx_missed_errors.. Increasing the rx_desc increases the time it takes for the issue to happen.. but I guess need to root cause why the fd's are not enough...  any hints on what to look for in my application will be helpful

Comment: @nmurshed this is good observation, I am open to talk with you over skype, zoom, google meet. Let me know if it's useful for a live debug.

Comment: @Vipin we can connect. Unfortunately, I won’t be able to divulge a lot of details about the application as its work related. 
How can I connect with you.

Comment: You can reach me on skype, zoom or google meet. If you can reproduce with standard application l2fwd, skeleton so we can debug

Comment: Not able to repro.. infact.. using the same binaries.. it's not reproduced on another server.. only diff is sender process is different. One thing I can see from capture is.. in the problematic setup.. there are lot of fragmentation .. the packet len is 9000 bytes.. fragmented to 1440. Not sure if that is playing a role...but application should handle it.

Comment: Can't find vipinpv85 in google meet.. maybe join https://meet.google.com/imf-fjqo-ozk

Comment: got disconnected : https://meet.google.com/imf-fjqo-ozk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DPDK counter `rx_missed_errors` infers these many packets were not processed which were received on the NIC. While `Rx-no-mbuf` represents the counters which showcase packets that were not DMA to CPU-Memory due to the absence of MBUF buffers. Hence the error is mostly in application logic either `Spending too much time processing the packets` or `recursive processing on the same MBUF array after rx_burst`.

[EDIT-1] Based on a couple of debugging attempts and pointers the issue is root caused to application logic. Summarizing the below

1. For incoming ARP requests the packets are processed and ARP reply is sent out on the same MBUF and `rte_pktmbuf_free` we called immediately right after `rte_Eth_tx_burst` - Issue Fixed
2. For IP packets, the IP header and UDP header are processed for the desired packet and necessary changes are made to the MBUF before transmission. - for certain conditions (count of packets) the logic enters to longer loops which stalls the function exit.

Note:

1. Fixing the above 2 issues seems to solve the issue.
2. Using DPDK-Pktgen to generate custom packets allows to narrow down specific code areas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help @Vipin. It was very nice talking to you. I never thought, you would give so much time. Thank you so much for sharing all the knowledge. Coudn't have done it without your help

Comment: Happy to help and share, best wishes for your project Niyaz

Comment: Even after fixing the code loop, the issue persists somewhat.. instead of the loop I get the below error and then the i assume the packet is messed up..                        i40e_dev_alarm_handler(): ICR0: malicious programming detected
i40e_handle_mdd_event(): Malicious Driver Detection event 0x02 on TX queue 1 PF number 0x01 VF number 0x00 device 0000:18:00.1
i40e_handle_mdd_event(): TX driver issue detected on PF

Comment: @nimurshed, Maclicious driver is result of sending (TX) incorrect packet descriptor. It is not result of RX

Comment: okay.. so the problem might still be somwhere messing up the buffer when reading the incoming packets.. But one thing is resolved that I now receive the packet always.